# Search for specific aspects on a map at a certain location

Tags: objective-c, macos, mapkit

How would I go about programming a function to interact with Apple's MapKit so that when a specific location(latitude/longitude) is given, the program will search for certain aspects within 5-10km radius on that map?

So for example, gets given geo-location of an airport, and searching for runways within a radius of that airport, then placing vectors marking the runway for viewing purposes and specific location of the runway.

How would I go about programming something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Just reading through the sample code, this is what you need:

```
// confine the map search area to the user's current location
MKCoordinateRegion newRegion;
newRegion.center.latitude = self.userLocation.latitude;
newRegion.center.longitude = self.userLocation.longitude;

// setup the area spanned by the map region:
// we use the delta values to indicate the desired zoom level of the map,
//      (smaller delta values corresponding to a higher zoom level)
//
newRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.112872;
newRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.109863;
```

And the [reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MapSearch/Listings/Classes_MyTableViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013332-Classes_MyTableViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_8).